# Why workflow event handler does not do its job?

Tags: axapta

I followed  [this guide](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/tinkerersnotebook/archive/2013/11/09/developing-a-product-approval-workflow-in-dynamics-ax-2012.aspx) step by step to create workflow to be able to approve items.

At the end the part of workflow is working just partially. The workflow is visible, it is changing state of item from ["NotSubmitted" to "Submitted"](http://extendingdynamicsax.com/2013/11/11/create-a-base-enumeration-to-track-the-approval-status/) but it looks like the the method [**completed**](http://extendingdynamicsax.com/2013/11/11/update-the-completed-method-on-the-approval-event-handler/) is never called so it does not change the status to **Approved**.

When the workflow is canceled the status is changed to "Rejected" so it is little weird.

So my question is: Which part of AX workflow from [this guide](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/tinkerersnotebook/archive/2013/11/09/developing-a-product-approval-workflow-in-dynamics-ax-2012.aspx) calls  the method **completed** on [workflowEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc623606.aspx) ? 
Microsoft dynamics AX 2012 R3

Comment: Did you read through the comments of the original guide article (http://extendingdynamicsax.com/2013/11/06/developing-a-product-approval-workflow-in-dynamics-ax-2012/)? Did you try to contact the author of the guide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Approve/Reject a work item that is submitted to the workflow try the following code snippet, for example approving a project budget:

```
ProjId                  _projId = '120152';
ProjBudget              _projBudget = ProjBudget::findOrCreateProjectBudget(_projId);
WorkflowWorkItemTable   workflowWorkItemTable;

while select workflowWorkItemTable where
    (workflowWorkItemTable.Type == WorkflowWorkItemType::WorkItem) &&
    (workflowWorkItemTable.Status == WorkflowWorkItemStatus::Pending) &&
    //workflowWorkItemTable.DueDateTime < DateTimeUtil::getSystemDateTime() &&
    workflowWorkItemTable.RefRecId == _projBudget.RecId &&
    workflowWorkItemTable.RefTableId == _projBudget.TableId
{
    WorkflowWorkItemActionManager::dispatchWorkItemAction(
                        workflowWorkItemTable, 
                        "@SYS325206",//Approved budget 
                        curUserId(), 
                        WorkflowWorkItemActionType::Complete, 
                        "ProjBudgetOrigWorkflowApprove",
                        false);
}
```

I don't have Access to Murray Fife's guide, but the following blogs have helped me inmeasureably with workflows:

- MSDN's [About Workflow Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc967429.aspx), especially [How to: Create a SubmitToWorkflow Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc583139.aspx)
- [How to auto-submit record into workflow](http://workflowax.wordpress.com/2010/06/23/how-to-auto-submit-record-into-workflow/), for AX 2009.
- [Colin's Dynamics AX 2012 blog](http://colinmitchell.net/dynamicsax/tag/workflow/)
- [Dynamics Workflow Wanderings](http://workflowax.wordpress.com/)